# How to remove tags <a> </a> with str_replace to a specific domain?

Tags: php, str-replace

I would like to remove the   tag from a specific domain with str_replace

```
  <a href="google.com/1235"> content1
    </a>
    <a href="somelink.com/2455"> content12
    </a>
    <a href="google2.com/3"> content13
    </a>
    <a href="some.com/34858"> content14
    </a>
    <a href="somelink.com/3"> content14
    </a>
    <a href="somelink.com/31111"> content14
    </a>
    <a href="somelink.com/3111d1"> content16
    </a> ........ ect ...
```

Here I want to remove the   tag to the domain: `somelink.com`

This is what I have :

```
$abcont = file_get_contents ("http://www.example.com");

preg_match_all ('{<a href=somelink.com/.*?> (. *?) </a>}', $abcont, $allLinksMatchs);

$abcont = str_replace ("<a href =", $allLinksMatchs, $abcont);
```

so that it turns out:

```
<a href="google.com/1235"> content1
    </a>
     content12

    <a href="google2.com/3"> content13
    </a>
    <a href="some.com/34858"> content14
    </a>
  content14

     content14

     content16
   ....... ect ...
```

Comment: And your question is _what_ ?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm why to use **str_replace** when there is **preg_replace**?

This code will work for you for single domain:

```
$domain = 'somelink.com';

$abcont = preg_replace("/<a href=\"{$domain}.+\">(.+)<\/a>/iUs", "$1", $abcont);
```

or if you want to do on multiple domains than instead of $domain variable we will use array $domains

```
$domains = ['somelink.com'];

$abcont = preg_replace("/<a href=\"(" . join("|", $domains) . ").+\">(.+)<\/a>/iUs", "$2", $abcont);
```

Comment: You should escape domain due to the `.` matching any character, so `preg_quote($domain, '/')` In addition I imagine you would want to use `{$domain}\/.+` So matches like `domain.com.eu` are not accidently matched (albeit unlikely) https://3v4l.org/7KiZK Note `somelink-com.com` and `somelink.com1` are incorrectly matched

Comment: Agree just didn't want to confuse this guy with additional preparation for domains with str_replace('.', '\', $domain)... or same for this join... in 99.99% cases this will work like he expected (based on situation)

Comment: No need for `str_replace()`, just use [`preg_quote()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), which will escape the provided domain name. Good practice, since the OP also made both mistakes in their`preg_match`

Comment: hello, how could I do to put several domains as you expose : $domains = ['somelink.com','domain.net','sddas.com']; Is that correct?

Comment: yep, just put domains you need into array $domains = ['domain1.com', 'domain2.com']; btw please accept answer if this solved your problem